# Using bitmap to take image from imageview

Tags: android

I'm having a problem using bitmap to take image from imageview... The code for using bitmap to take image by its ID is: (my picture name = test_image)(my imageview = imageView)

```
Bitmap image;
...
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R. drawable.test_image);
```

But I want it to take the image inside the imageview.Without specifying the image name.

Due to the reason that I want to upload image into the imageview and process the image that is in imageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

This is how you can get bitmap from any imageview

Answer (score 0):

```
private Bitmap getImageViewFromBitmap(ImageView v){
    Bitmap bm=((BitmapDrawable)v.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    return bm;
}
```

Comment: Its being cast in BitmapDrawable , not the assumption.

Comment: Where should I put this piece of code?  Is it inside onCreate?

Comment: anotherimageview.setImageBitmap(getImageViewFromBitmap(imageview));